# How to make a square move in short consecutive stretches?

Tags: java, javafx

I am very new to javafx (and programming in general) so apologies for any ugliness. What I want to do is make a square move across the window, but not in one single move. I want it to move in short consecutive stretches, what I've got looks something like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(1000), sq);
tt.setToX(1);
tt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
tt.playFromStart();
```

My problem is that it just moves forward and then jumps back to its original position again. I am pretty sure that I have to have one of these somewhere

```
sq.setX(sq.getX() + sq.getTranslateX());
sq.setTranslateX(0);
```

but I can't really figure out where to put it.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Didnt understood well how is the movement you want

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to do this, here are a couple:

1. Use a [SequentialTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) consisting of multiple [TranslateTransitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) that are interspersed with [PauseTransitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html).
2. Set up a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) which manipulates the translation value of the square via a series of [KeyValues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html).

The example below uses a the SequentialTransition method:

[image: step1]
[image: step2]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class EyeOfSauron extends Application {
    private static final int N_STEPS = 5;
    private static final int SQUARE_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int STEP = SQUARE_SIZE * 2;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);
        rect.setFill(Color.DARKRED);

        SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();
        for (int i = 0; i < N_STEPS; i++) {
            PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(250));
            TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), rect);
            tt.setByX(STEP);
            tt.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

            sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(
                    pt, tt
            );
        }
        sequentialTransition.getChildren().add(new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(250)));
        sequentialTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
        sequentialTransition.setCycleCount(Transition.INDEFINITE);

        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        new Group(rect),
                        N_STEPS * STEP + SQUARE_SIZE,
                        SQUARE_SIZE,
                        Color.BISQUE
                )
        );
        stage.show();

        sequentialTransition.playFromStart();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem (from what I see) is that the you're calling `tt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);` which causes the animation to **repeat** indefinitely. Set it to `tt.setCycleCount(1);` should cause it to run once, ending with the square where it left off.